# Unique values based on group and timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got the following data (see below) in my database.

```json
[
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  }
]
```

Each item may have a duplicated date, but a different importtime.

I was wondering if it's possible to have a single query that groups the date, and only retrieves the last item (based on the importtime).

```json
[
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  }
]
```

For example; I would like that the json returned

```json
[
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domain.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  }
]
```

Comment: presented data in your table is it one json field or rows of your table please clarify

Comment: each item presents one row in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table
where true
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by date order by importtime desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: That's almost good. But what if there are multiple suppliers and domains? Then still only 2 rows will be returned right?

Comment: yes, but if you want to group by them also - just add to `partition by` part - that easy - make sense? so it will be `partition by date, supplier, domain order by ...`

Comment: Not really, `partition by date, domain` doesn't work.. Man, I thought I knew SQL.. Thanks for helping tho.

Comment: I will; thanks. Ive posted it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397753/multiple-unique-values-based-on-group-and-timestamp since your answer was technically correct :)

Comment: ok. will check it ...