# Multiple unique values based on group and timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got the following data in my database:

```json
[
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:09.937 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.45"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:05:21.708 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:07.105 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:44.882 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  }
]
```

Each item may have a duplicated datefield, but a different importtime.

I’m not quite sure if this has anything too do with grouping or ordering; but I just want it to return the maximum threshold, of each domain and supplier based on the date. In my example the threshold is always the same; but it will get higher during the day, hence I added the importtime field.

```json
[
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domaina.nl",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "transip",
    "domain": "domainb.com",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:12:17.304 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "14.97"
  },
  {
    "importtime": "2021-09-30 18:11:38.785 UTC",
    "date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "supplier": "veri",
    "domain": "domainc.x",
    "threshold": "2.47"
  }
]
```

Comment: please clarify - what attributes you want to group by ?

Comment: The highest threshold should be taken - and the date may only be there once, thus grouped by date and supplier.

Comment: the expected result you presented - cannot be done if you group by date and supplier, but rather can be done by grouping bu date and domain!! please double check your question and fix it - so we can help further :o)\

Comment: Would it help if the table was splitted?

Thus one table for veri, and one table for transip?

And yes; then grouped by date and domain

Comment: i don't think there is any issue with input data you shown. the problem is in requirement you presented. a) it is not consistent and b) expected output does not match to that requirement. so you need to rewrite your question with clear logic of what you want.

Comment: I’m not quite sure how to reformat my question. I’m also not quite sure how this method is called - hence the confusion about the names. I just want it to return the maximum threshold, of each domain and supplier based on the date.

Comment: exactly - make sure you explain this in your question (not in comments)

Comment: You’re right. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select date, supplier, domain, max(threshold)
from mytable
group by date, supplier, domain
order by date, supplier, domain
```